# How to get rid of exported symbols from a windows static library?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, linker

I'm linking my executable with a third-party static library that was compiled with wrong defines passed to the C compiler. The same library is also available as a DLL, and the static version was compiled such that all of the symbols are exported. This of course makes no sense for a static library, since the exports propagate to the executable (or a DLL) such a library would be integrated into.

When I link the executable with this library, the symbols from the library are exported from the executable. I'm not concerned about the generated .lib and .exp files. I need to get rid of the exported symbols in the executable itself.

What I need is a way to either:

1. Force the linker's list of exported symbols to be cleared, or
2. Edit the object files extracted from the library to "unexport" the symbols.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to build the project. The library is provided as a .LIB file, and I can use the librarian to extract the object files and dumpbin to confirm presence of exported symbols.

At the moment I don't want to bother the vendor to fix it, or rather, I don't expect them to reply before I grow old.

Comment: This is inevitable, the linker does what you asked it to do with no option to undo it again.  It merely produces two small junk files that you don't actually use.  If you really hate it that much then just delete them again in a post-build event.

Comment: The junk files are not an issue. The issue is that the .EXE file has exported symbols!

Comment: If you find a way to import them then please do share the secret.

Comment: There's plenty of dll injection tools out there. [This one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dllinjector/files/dllinjector/0.1/) is perhaps the most minimal example. Upon loading (injection), the DLL can bind to symbols exported from the executable.

Comment: Alas, my executable already exports other symbols since it uses plugins, and the architecture is such that the plugins need some symbols from the executable. Alas, I simply don't want to export the symbols from that particular third party library.

Comment: Never mind that [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) can load executables as well as DLLs, so you can actually link to other executables's symbols from your executable, directly. In this respect, an executable is no different from a DLL. Basically whatever you link as a DLL you can link as an EXE and still use it. With a few minor caveats.

Comment: The format of an executable file is documented, so failing an existing solution you could build your own.

Comment: Try using a .def file when linking.  I believe EXPORT statements in this file will override the information in the object files.  You can then use the NONAME option; strictly speaking, the symbols will still be exported, but only by ordinal, not by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely override the symbols that are exported from a PE image (.exe or .dll) created during linking, one has to link with an `.exp` file. Merely [linking with a `.def` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dot-def-files-as-linker-input) can only add symbols to the exported list, not remove from it.

1. Create a `.def` file. If you don't want to export anything, it will be almost-empty:

   ```
   NAME "YourExecutableBaseName"
   ```

   This would be for `YourExecutableBaseName.exe` or `YourExecutableBaseName.dll`. The basename in the `.def` should match the linker's output file name, otherwise there will be a warning.
2. Create an `.exp` file from the `.def` file using `LIB`.
3. [Link the executable with this `.exp` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dot-exp-files-as-linker-input). This exports file completely defines any and all exported symbols, and the linker will not export anything that's not there.

Comment: This did NOT work in VS 2015. The `.exp` file is binary. Linking with a text version gives: `test.exp : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0xF`

Comment: @RustyX The `.exp` file is binary and is the file you should link with. You're not supposed to link with the `.def` file, even though it [it works when done correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dot-def-files-as-linker-input). I've made this clearer.

Comment: I have a similar situation: static library linked to a DLL causing some of the static library's symbols to be exported by the DLL. Does this solution applies when making a DLL too?

Comment: @Calmarius Yes, this applies to any loadable binary output of the linker - so both EXE and DLL. The two fundamentally differ only in some header information are identical file formats, just wish slightly different metadata inside.